# Dúvida Laravel Queries SQL?

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Estou iniciando com as `SQL` de `Laravel` procurei bastante mais não obtive uma resposta de como fazer um `AND` depois de um `where`, segue código de exemplo para implementar um `AND`.

SQL:

```
UPDATE contas
SET valor_titulo = 0,
WHERE id_contrato = 2 
AND data_vencimento = '2017-05-05'
```

Como estou fazendo no Laravel:

```
DB::table('contas')
        ->where('id_contrato', $options['id_contrato'])
        ->update(['valor_titulo' => $attributes['valor_titulo']);
```

Como colocar um `AND` nesta estrutura?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

```
DB::table('contas')
    ->where('id_contrato', $options['id_contrato'])
    ->where('data_vencimento', $options['data_vencimento'])
    ->update(['valor_titulo' => $attributes['valor_titulo']);
```

ou assim:

```
DB::table('contas')
    ->where([
        ['id_contrato','=', $options['id_contrato']],
        ['data_vencimento','=', $options['data_vencimento']],
     ])
    ->update(['valor_titulo' => $attributes['valor_titulo']);
```

ou até assim:

```
DB::table('contas')
    ->where(function($query) use ($options){
            $query->where('id_contrato',$options['id_contrato'])
                  ->where('data_vencimento',$options['data_vencimento']);
      })
    ->update(['valor_titulo' => $attributes['valor_titulo']);
```

<sub>**Referencias:**</sub>

- [Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries)
- [Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: Virgilio Novic tentei com a segunda opção e funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado pela ajuda.